# Can I cap old, live wiring to remove the switch?

Tags: electrical

I have still-live-but-not-in-use electric baseboard heating with controls all over the house. I'd like to remove them, but the wires are still live.

Can I just cap them using a wire-nut and put a blank receptical cover over it?

Comment: Similar: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/20314/how-can-i-safely-remove-an-outlet-from-service?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a good start, but you will still have live wires running around in your walls for no constructive purpose.

Find the breaker that controls the circuit, and turn it off.  Check all your other installed loads (sump pump, etc.) to make sure everything else still works - the several heaters should be the only thing on the breaker, but sometimes people do odd things.  Once you're sure of that...

Turn off the main, take off the panel front (be warned that if your main breaker is inside the panel, some metal parts inside the panel are still energized!!)  Then pull the breaker off the panel if it unclips (as it's easier to work with this way), remove the wires from the breaker, cap the wires in the service panel, put the breaker back with a N/C label on it, and put the panel front back on.

Comment: Beware, if relevant to your jurisdiction: NFPA 1 (2015): 11.1.2.3 "Permanent wiring abandoned in place shall be tagged or otherwise identified at its termination and junction points as “Abandoned in Place” or removed from all accessible areas and insulated from contact with other live electrical wiring or devices."